# JS Doc , is there any way to specify "Choice" param?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm pretty new to JS and JS Doc and I had a question for optional parameters.

Imagine this function

```
/**
 * @param {string} [param1]
 * @param {string} [param2]
 */
const foo= (){...}
```

As JSDoc says, an optional parameter is like this

```
/**
 * @param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.
 */
```

Is there any way, with my example, to define 2 optional parameters but at least one is required ?(If param1 is set, param2 is not and if param2 is set, param1 is not).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets around the parameter name means it's optional.
To make it required, remove the squared brackets.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} param1 - required
 * @param {string} [param2] - optional
 */
const foo= (){...}
```

You could also just use Typescript, for a more robust type system.

```
const foo = (param1: string, param2?: string);
```

`Is there any way, with my example, to define 2 optional parameters but at least one is required ?(If param1 is set, param2 is not and if param2 is set, param1 is not).`

To solve this problem, you can define multiple function overloads.

```
function foo(email:string);
function foo(username:string){
  if(username) return "Used username overlaod";
  if(email) return "Used email overload";
}
```

For JSDoc it's harder. Looks like this:

```js
/**
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} username
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} email
 */
function foo(value) {
  // ...
}
```

I would recommend using TS over JSDoc.

Comment: My question was about JSDoc only not the code itself, and for you there is no way to do it, thanks for your reply.